# Answer to android login request via PHP

Tags: php, android, networking, authentication

i know this could look like a really simple question to somebody, but i'm quite new to PHP. By the way..

I want a user to login on an android app, and this login request has to be handled by a PHP page, i wrote this for the android part:

```
try{
            String url = "https://MYWEBSITE:80/login?username=" + mEmail + "&password=" + mPassword;
            HttpParams parameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(parameters, 1000 * 60 * 2);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(parameters, 0);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(parameters);

            //prepare the HTTP GET call
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            //get the response entity
            HttpEntity entity = httpClient.execute(httpget).getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                //get the response content as a string
                String response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                //consume the entity
                entity.consumeContent();

                // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed, shut down the connection
                // manager to ensure immediate deallocation of all system resources
                httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but i have no idea what to write in the PHP file, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have to create a table lets say "users"

```
USER TABLE
==========

        ID (Primary)        USERNAME (VARCHAR)         PASSWORD (VARCHAR)
    ============================================================================

             1                webzar                       abc123

             2                someone                      222222
```

Then create a file login.php

```
login.php
=========


    <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("YOUR DB NAME") or die(mysql_error());

    $username = $_GET['username']; // GET USERNAME

    $password= $_GET['password']; // GET PASSWORD


    if($username != '' and $password != '') 
    {
         $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username ' and password = '$password'") or die(mysql_error());

         if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) // CHECK FOR USER CREDENTIALS
         {
              // IF INFO IS CORRECT

              $fetch = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
              echo 'Logged In';
         }
        else
        {
             echo 'Cannot Login!';
        }


    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had another little problem, but i fixed it on my own. Thank you again!

Comment: Its pleasure my friend :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what the rest of your backend looks like.

For example, if you have a MySQL database of your users, you need to simply check if the username and password match the ones stored in you database and return a flag that says "valid username and password, authentication succeeded".

Maybe you could give more information about how you are authenticating the user on your website and what kind of database do you use to store the information about the users.